# UWP, Windows App: Cannot add Files manually

Tags: javascript, windows, visual-studio, uwp, app-certification-kit

When I try to run the Windows Store App Certification Tests for my Project I always get the errors you can see on the following images.

These errors seem weird because they even occur in the `main.min.js` file which is empty and in the via Visual Studio included jQuery files.

In addition it also complains that all files I added manually are not `UTF-8`

How do I fix that?

[image: Windows App Certification Test Failed]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but due to some reason Visual Studio created the files listed above in the wrong Encoding Format.

So I ended up resaving each of them with the UTF-8 Encoding Format.